# How should I handle this move in rust?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a basic understanding of lifetimes and how borrowing works but I am just beginning to understand in practice.

```rust
enum MealTime {
    Breakfast,
    Lunch,
    Dinner,
}
struct Item {
    name: String,
    station: String,
    meal: MealTime,
}
```

```rust
    for meal in [MealTime::Breakfast, MealTime::Lunch, MealTime::Dinner] {

        let main_section = doc
            .select(match &meal {
                MealTime::Breakfast => &bsectionsel,
                MealTime::Lunch => &lsectionsel,
                MealTime::Dinner => &dsectionsel,
            })
            .next()
            .unwrap();

        for sections in main_section.select(&itemsectionsel) {
            let stationc = sections
                .select(&stationsel)
                .next()
                .unwrap()
                .text()
                .next()
                .unwrap()
                .trim();

            for itemname in sections.select(&buttonsel) {
                let itemnamec = itemname.text().next().unwrap().trim();

                let newitem = Item {
                    name: itemnamec.to_string(),
                    station: stationc.to_string(),
                    meal: meal,
                };

                item_list.push(newitem);

                println!("{}\nStation: {}\n", newitem.name, newitem.station,);
            }
        }
    }
```

gives: `error[E0382]: use of moved value: meal`

```
meal: meal,
      ^^^^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
```

I want to have an enum representing which meal has been selected assigned to an instance of a struct I have made to represent a meal item. I don't understand why this error occurs, because in my mind this owner 'meal' will be reassigned in every iteration of the loop.

Comment: But you have 3 nested loops, it is reassigned in the outer most loop, it isn't in the inner loops. You either need to call derive and call clone() on meal, or if your enum is simple like it is here, just derive copy, and it will copy every time there is a move.

Comment: @Prime_Aqasix Thanks, didn't know about that macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 nested loops, it is reassigned in the outer most loop, it isn't in the inner loops.

```
for meal in [MealTime::Breakfast, MealTime::Lunch, MealTime::Dinner] {

    let main_section = doc
        .select(match &meal {
            MealTime::Breakfast => &bsectionsel,
            MealTime::Lunch => &lsectionsel,
            MealTime::Dinner => &dsectionsel,
        })
        .next()
        .unwrap();

    for sections in main_section.select(&itemsectionsel) { //<-- second inner loop here

        let stationc = sections
            .select(&stationsel)
            .next()
            .unwrap()
            .text()
            .next()
            .unwrap()
            .trim();

        for itemname in sections.select(&buttonsel) {// <-- third inner loop here
            let itemnamec = itemname.text().next().unwrap().trim();

            let newitem = Item {
                name: itemnamec.to_string(),
                station: stationc.to_string(),
                meal: meal, // This is called multiple times per outermost loop
            };

            item_list.push(newitem);

            println!("{}\nStation: {}\n", newitem.name, newitem.station,);
        }
    }
}
```

If your enums is as simple as it was in the code you provided, just put

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum MealTime {
    Breakfast,
    Lunch,
    Dinner,
}
```

above your enum.

See [Copy trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html)